# How can I lookup LaTeX symbols in Vim?

Tags: autocompletion, filetype-tex

Can I integrate some form of symbol completion to Vim? Dedicated TeX editors like TeXMaker provide a list of symbols for completion (for example, `\al` shows a list with `\alpha`, `\la` shows `\lambda` and `\langle`).

Please note that TeX has a rather large number of symbols, so suggestions involving manual mapping of `\al` to `\alpha` would be useless.

Related plugins I have:

- [SuperTab](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) with `let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType="context"` and
  `set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete`
- [LaTeX-Box](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box)

If it matters, I use XeLaTeX for compiling.

Related:

- [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)

Comment: Complementary to this, there's [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) for when you know how to draw a character but you don't remember the name of the command.

Comment: I'm planning to add such a feature to [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex), based on the dictionary completion as used by for instance `latex-suite`. `vimtex` is a relatively new plugin and is based on LaTeX-Box, so it should feel somewhat familiar.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg I switched to vimtex recently. Did you get around to adding this feature? Then I can nuke the dictionary, and perhaps you can post using vimtex as an answer.

Comment: Yes. I recommend that you use `snippets` for complicated expansions, but for simple ones, you can look at `:h vimtex-imaps` fo a description of the feature implemented in vimtex.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To expand commands in LaTeX, I use a dictionary copied from [latex-suite](https://github.com/gerw/vim-latex-suite) (in details, [this one](https://github.com/gerw/vim-latex-suite/blob/master/ftplugin/latex-suite/dictionaries/dictionary)) and put it in `~/.vim/dictionaries` and then using

```
autocmd FileType * exec("setlocal dictionary+=".$HOME."/.vim/dictionaries/".expand('<amatch>'))
set completeopt=menuone,longest,preview
set complete+=k
```

Idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723493/latex-and-vim-usage). I use it with supertab; the dictionary file is not really complete (it has `\alpha` but not `\langle`) but that would be a matter of completing it...

One option for adding symbols would be to parse (not complex --- just a bit of shell magic will do it) the [detexify database](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kirel/detexify/master/lib/latex/symbols.yaml). For example, one could use:

```
{ curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kirel/detexify/master/lib/latex/symbols.yaml |
   grep -Po '(?<=\\)[[:alpha:]]{2,}';
   curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gerw/vim-latex-suite/master/ftplugin/latex-suite/dictionaries/dictionary
} | sort -u | tee ~/.vim/dictionaries/tex
```

Comment: I knew that @muru would not resist to find the right script! Btw, would be better to add also the keywords from latex-suite dictionary...

Comment: Done. It added 600+ words to the list from detexify. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a snippet completion plugin like [Snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) or [Ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips), in conjunction with [this multi-language snippets collection](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets).