# Can I give YouCompleteMe a static list of completions?

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-you-complete-me

I am using the  Julia programming language, and as of right now, there are no good syntax-completer for VIM.

I am working on one, but haven't fully got my head around how to hook into `ycmd`.
Til I find some free time to delve in deeply.
I was wondering (if as a stopgap), I could give YCM a list of all completions I want made available.
Then I could at least make all the functions from the Standard Library syntax complete.

Or since I have code right now, that will take a source file, and output all completions for any packages it uses etc, I could generate this list of completions per file, and only have to regenerate when more packages were made use of.

Is this possible?
It wouldn't end up smart I guess since it would not be able to detect when a `.` should be used as a trigger, but I think anything is better than nothing.

Comment: See `:help ins-completion` and `:help 'complete'`.

Comment: @romainl helpful to an extent. I guess I could use "dictionary" completion, but that would be dropping out of YCM, into normal vim completion stuff, unless I can set YCM to dictionary mode.
I assume that is why you are commenting not answering.

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/138

Comment: I'm commenting because YCM has documentation and an issue tracker. That's where you are supposed to look for answers, not here.

Comment: @romainl that doesn't seem inline with your first comment -- which was a lookup to *vim's* documentation. YCM's documentation is not particularly excellent -- not compared to asking someone with experience, thus Stack Exchange sites.
Most plugins have documentation and an issue tracker, yet we have 22 other questions on YCM.
And 19 on NerdTree,  18 on Utilisnips, 17 on Airline, 15 on vim-latex etc.
I'm not seeing what you are getting at?

Vim itself has documentation and an issue tracker, perhaps we should not use this Stack Exchange site at all?
http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21/

Comment: 1. YCM is too bloated, too hard to install and too hard to configure with regard to its supposed benefit. 2. Its small user base and the opacity of its code base make it hard to support that thing. 3. I comment the same thing every time a `$BIG_PLUGIN` question pops up. 3. YCM supposedly defaults to keyword completion when no omni-completion is found. That's why I pointed to the built-in methods.

Comment: I think using syntax highlighting keywords and dictionaries are the way to do this for now. That's how I use YCM in minor filetypes (like logrotate or Upstart configuration files).

Comment: @muru do you think you could put an example online somewhere? Either as an answer, or as a dump of files that I could investigate until I understood, and then I could self-answer this.

Comment: Here's an example for LaTeX: https://gist.github.com/murukeshm/16011036e486a35e0d93d1f83ef38150 this is my evolution of http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2360/205. It uses supertab for `omnifunc`, and then, with semantic completion, I get the fuzzy matching of YCM when I start typing a `​\​`. It shows two ways: with tags, and with a syntax file.

Comment: @muru thanks, I'll take a proper look later.